# React app won't render info from props even though I can console log it

Tags: reactjs, components, console.log

So ideally my parent component is mapping through a database and rendering them based on the user's choice. Right now right now the information is being passed correctly and the app is rendering what I need it too (the card component) in the correct amount however it is full of dummy info. (Someone clicks beer, there are three beer types in the database, the app renders three card components full of dummy info).

Here is the parent component:

```js
class Render  extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Here are your props", props);
  }
  

componentDidMount() {
      let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/drinks',
      };

      let drinks =  [];
      console.log("this is",this);
      axios.request(options)
        .then( (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.setState({ drinks: response.data })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
  render() {
    
    console.log("this.state is",[this.state])
    let stateArray = [this.state]

    if (stateArray[0] == null) {
      console.log("returning with nothing")
      return <div></div>
    }

  let firstElement = stateArray[0];

   let  drinks = firstElement.drinks; 
    

  let drinkChoice = this.props.reduxState.drinkChoice

  console.log("drinkchoice is here" , drinkChoice)

  // const props = this.props

  console.log("just drinks", drinks)


  let drinkInfo = {
    type: this.state.drinks.type,
    name:  this.state.drinks.name,
    manufacturer: this.state.drinks.manufacturer,
    rating: this.state.drinks.rating,
    date: this.state.drinks.date,
    description: this.state.drinks.description,
    favorite: this.state.drinks.favorite
  }

  let cardComponents = drinks.map((drink) =>{
    if (drink.type === drinkChoice) {
      return (<InfoCard props={this.state.drinks} />)
    } else {
      return <div>Nothing to Report</div>
    }})

  return (
      <div>
          <div>{cardComponents}</div>
      </div>
   )
  }
}

export default Render
```

Now I need it to render the actual database information for each entry. In the child/cardcomponent- I can console.log the props and it will correctly show the right information. It's getting through. But anytime I try to be more specific ( props.name ) it turns to undefined.

I have been at this for days and i'm so confused. The information is right there! I just need to grab it!

Here is the code for the child/card component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
  expand: {
    transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
    }),
  },
  expandOpen: {
    transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
  },
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: red[500],
  },
}));



export default function InfoCard(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

if( props.length <= 0 )  {
    return (<div></div>);
} else {

console.log("props are here")
console.log( props  )

console.log("props dot name")
console.log ( props.name )
}
props.each(function (drink) {
  console.log(drink.name);
  });

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
        title = { props.name }
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Where have I gone wrong? I feel like i've tried every possible iteration of console.log and drink.name. I'm at the end of my rope.

Thanks for any and all guidance.

[sccreengrab of console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fwu0.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: are you saying that when you `console.log(props)` you see an object with a name property that has a defined value ... but then when you `console.log(props.name)` you see `undefined`?  If so it seems like you might have too many console.logs, and they're giving you confusing results, because that should not be possible.

Comment: Perhaps add your console.log output...

Comment: @machineghost  Yes! That's what i'm saying! I have attached a screenshot of my console.log so you can see exactly what it gives me.

It is driving me INSANE.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing in your log of `props` is an *array* of objects.  Those objects have names, but the array itself does not, so when you `console.log(props.name)` it doesn't work and you see undefined.  If you try `console.log(props[0].name)`, for instance, you should see a name.

But what's strange here is that `props` should **NOT** be an array: it should be an object (whose keys map to the JSX element's attributes).  For instance:

```
<InfoCard name="Bob"/>
```

would create a props *object* of:

```
{name: 'Bob'}
```

But when you log your props, you see an array, and that means you've somehow/somewhere replaced the actual `props` object with an array.  Without seeing the code where you actually create `<Infocard>`, I can't speak to the details.

P.S. It *might* be possible to do this if you did something like:

```
`<MyComponent {...[{ name: 'Bob']} />`
```

... but honestly I'm not sure if that even works, and it seems like a bad idea even if it does.

Comment: Okay, I guess that's here in the parent component where I did that. 

let stateArray = [this.state]

But if I take it out of the array everything breaks. Any suggestions on how to better pass that info so it's easier to reach? And thank you for responding.

Comment: You just have to pass the values you want as JSX attributes.  However, if you want to move data from state to props, or vice-versa, ES5 has given Javascript some neat "tricks" for doing so like combined variable/property names and the spread operator (`...`).  For instance, let's say you had a name, a price and a description in state, and you wanted to pass all three to a component Foo.  You could do something like `const { name, description, price } = this.state;` and then: `<Foo {...{ name, description, price }} />`.